# Loading external blocks of XSL code

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Is it possible to load external blocks of XSL code similar to how you can load blocks of code in, for example aspx include?
EG:

```
    <xsl:if test="$ShowNextButton='No'">
        <!-- A Block of external code would be loaded here -->
    </xsl:if>
```

I'm using XSLT 1.0 if that makes a difference.

Comment: and what xslt parser do you use? If it exists it would be an specific parser feature. You could invent something with an XSLT that processes your xslt that holds a node that tells what xslt to merge...tricky...

Comment: Sorry. Not sure I follow? What do you mean by xslt parser? Sorry to be so dim, I'm just a lowly front-end developer :)

Comment: @user1001421: You need to acquaint yourself with the XSLT `xsl:import` and `xsl:include` instructions. However, they are unconditional. At present XSLT 1.0 doesn't allow dynamic conditional inclusion. XSLT 2.0 allows some very limited conditional, compile-time inclusion, by using the `use-when` attribute.

Comment: This sounds like a bit of a none starter then with my setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your blocks of "external XSL code" can be put in a named template, you can do this easily.

Here's a generic example using a main XSLT stylesheet (base.xsl) and including an external XSLT stylesheet (include.xsl).

**input.xml**

```
<test>
  <foo trigger-template="yes">
    <bar>Original "bar".</bar>
  </foo>
  <foo trigger-template="no">
    <bar>Original "bar".</bar>
  </foo>
</test>
```

**base.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:include href="include.xsl"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <foo>
      <xsl:if test="@trigger-template='yes'">
        <xsl:call-template name="external-template">
          <xsl:with-param name="statement" select="'Successfully called external XSL code!'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </foo>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**include.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template name="external-template">
    <xsl:param name="statement"/>
    <bar><xsl:value-of select="$statement"/></bar>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output.xml**

```
<test>
   <foo>
      <bar>Successfully called external XSL code!</bar>
      <bar>Original "bar".</bar>
   </foo>
   <foo>
      <bar>Original "bar".</bar>
   </foo>
</test>
```